# Guide to creating a contact form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, contact-form

I am trying to teach myself RoR and am building a site, and want to include a contact form, with "Persons Email" "Subject" and "Message", then a submit button, which will send an email to my email address.

I can't find a simple straightforward guide for beginners for rails 4 that goes through this step by step. So if anyone knows of one or is willing to create a guide, it would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I only have done the visual part, now need to get it to actually send the emails:

```
              <form  class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-lg ">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="message">Message</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" class="form-control input-lg"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit Message</button>
    </div>
</form><!-- End contact-form -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Catch this - link to a [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). This guide will show you how to create a simple app. I believe, you will be able to make your contact form after that. And about sending mails - here's a guide to [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). It will teach you how to send emails from Rails application.

With power of these guides combined, you'll be able to accomplish your task :)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to you (or anyone else), [this](https://gist.github.com/stevecondylios/e819a296167a31578d82fac881963789) is a straight forward guide to making a contact form but in rails 5 (and in production too, which is handy, not just development). Not sure how it goes for rails 4